# Yii:Upload CSV file to database

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to save a csv file to database and finding some issues with it.

controller:

```
$mod = new Csv;
if(isset($_POST['Csv']))
{
$mod->attributes=$_POST['Csv'];
if(!empty($_FILES['Csv']['tmp_name']['csv']))
{
$file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($mod,'csv');
$fp = fopen($file->tempName, 'r');
if($fp)
{
do 
{
 $line = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",");
 echo $line[0]; 
 echo $line[1]; 

 $mod['mobile'] = $line[0];
 $mod['name'] = $line[1];
 $mod->insert();

 }
 while( ($line = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ";")) != FALSE);
 }
 }}
```

I'm able to store only first record of my csv file. All the other records are stored as NULL. I dont know what I'm missing here

Answer (score 0):

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/442/upload-csv-file/

```
  $mod->save();
```

instead of

```
  $mod->insert();
```